# Sum columns from two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is the cost table and the other is the payment table, the cost table contains the cost of product with the product name.

```
 Cost Table
  id    |   cost   |  name
   1    |   100    |   A
   2    |   200    |   B
   3    |   200    |   A


  Payment Table
  pid  | amount    | costID
  1    |   10      |   1
  2    |   20      |   1
  3    |   30      |   2
  4    |   50      |   1
```

Now I have to sum the total of cost by the same `name` values, and as well sum the total amount of payments by the costID, like the query below

```
 totalTable

name | sum(cost)  |  sum(amount) |
  A  |  300       |     80       |
  B  |  200       |     30       |
```

However I have been working my way around this using the query below but I think I am doing it very wrong.

```
                SELECT 
                    b.name,
                    b.sum(cost),
                    a.sum(amount)

                FROM 
                      `Payment Table` a

                 LEFT JOIN
                      `Cost Table` b 
                ON   
                      b.id=a.costID


                      GROUP by b.name,a.costID
```

I would be grateful if somebody would help me with my queries or better still an idea as to how to go about it. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you need to group on `a.costID` - if you remove that, does it work?

Comment: You need to "Sum" before you join. as the one to many join between cost and payments ic causing an inflated sums.

Comment: How name `A` has two id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t2.name, sum(t2.cost), coalesce(sum(t1.amount), 0) as amount
from (
   select id, name, sum(cost) as cost
   from `Cost`
   group by id, name
) t2
left join (
   select costID, sum(amount) as amount
   from `Payment`
   group by CostID
) t1 on t2.id = t1.costID
group by t2.name
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13578/13)

Answer (score 1):

You need do the calculation in separated query and then join them together.

- First one is straight forward.
- Second one you need to get the `name` asociated to that payment based in the `cost_id`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13578/9)**

```
SELECT C.`name`, C.`sum_cost`, COALESCE(P.`sum_amount`,0 ) as `sum_amount`
FROM (
    SELECT `name`, SUM(`cost`) as `sum_cost`
    FROM `Cost`
    GROUP BY `name`
    ) C
LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT `Cost`.`name`, SUM(`Payment`.`amount`) as `sum_amount`
    FROM `Payment`
    JOIN `Cost` 
       ON `Payment`.`costID` = `Cost`.`id`
    GROUP BY `Cost`.`name`
  ) P
  ON C.`name` =  P.`name`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| name | sum_cost | sum_amount |
|------|----------|------------|
|    A |      300 |         80 |
|    B |      200 |         30 |
```

Comment: Thanks this also works well, thanks for your effort +1

Comment: I wish i could accept both answers, thanks once again

Comment: Well is up to you to choose which one accept based on what you believe solve better your question. I can argue my answer is better because at least try to explain what is happening instead just the code. Also even when potashin say submited first, he deleted his first answer because was wrong. And is until the final edit 4 min after mine his answer is correct. Even he use my sqlFiddle to test the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. For one thing, the column references should be qualified, not the aggregate functions.

This is invalid:

```
 table_alias.SUM(column_name)
```

Should be:

```
 SUM(table_alias.column_name)
```

This query should return the first two columns you are looking for:

```
SELECT c.name         AS `name`
     , SUM(c.cost)    AS `sum(cost)`
  FROM `Cost Table` c
 GROUP BY c.name
 ORDER BY c.name
```

When you introduce a join to another table, like `Product Table`, where `costid` is *not* UNIQUE, you have the potential to produce a (partial) Cartesian product.

To see what that looks like, to see what's happening, remove the `GROUP BY` and the aggregate `SUM()` functions, and take a look at the detail rows returned by a query with the join operation.

```
  SELECT c.id               AS `c.id`
       , c.cost             AS `c.cost`
       , c.name             AS `c.name`
       , p.pid              AS `p.pid`
       , p.amount           AS `p.amount`
       , p.costid           AS `p.costid`
    FROM `Cost Table` c
    LEFT
    JOIN `Payment Table` p
      ON p.costid = c.id
   ORDER BY c.id, p.pid
```

That's going to return:

```
 c.id | c.cost |  c.name | p.pid | p.amount | p.costid
 1    |    100 |  A      | 1     |       10 | 1       
 1    |    100 |  A      | 2     |       20 | 1       
 1    |    100 |  A      | 4     |       50 | 1       
 2    |    200 |  B      | 3     |       30 | 2
 3    |    200 |  A      | NULL  |     NULL | NULL
```

Notice that we are getting *three* copies of the id=1 row from `Cost Table`.

So, if we modified that query, adding a `GROUP BY c.name`, and wrapping c.cost in a SUM() aggregate, we're going to get an inflated value for total `cost`.

To avoid that, we can aggregate the `amount` from the `Payment Table`, so we get only one row for each `costid`. Then when we do the join operation, we won't be producing duplicate copies of rows from `Cost`.

Here's a query to aggregate the total amount from the `Payment Table`, so we get a *single* row for each `costid`.

```
  SELECT p.costid
       , SUM(p.amount) AS tot_amount
    FROM `Payment Table` p 
   GROUP BY p.costid
   ORDER BY p.costid
```

That would return:

```
  costid | tot_amount
  1      | 80
  2      | 30
```

We can use the results from that query as if it were a table, by making that query an "inline view".  In this example, we assign an alias of `v` to the query results. (In the MySQL venacular, an "inline view" is called a "derived table".)

```
SELECT c.name                      AS `name`
     , SUM(c.cost)                 AS `sum_cost`
     , IFNULL(SUM(v.tot_amount),0) AS `sum_amount`
  FROM `Cost Table` c
  LEFT
  JOIN ( -- inline view to return total amount by costid 
         SELECT p.costid
              , SUM(p.amount) AS tot_amount
           FROM `Payment Table` p
          GROUP BY p.costid
          ORDER BY p.costid
       ) v
    ON v.costid = c.id
 GROUP BY c.name
 ORDER BY c.name
```

Comment: Great explain. But two things a) You need use `LEFT JOIN` you can have `Cost` without `Payments`. b) name can have different `id`, but not sure if that is a typo error.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: good catch, i missed the outer join on that last query (fixed). Also added IFNULL around the SUM(), to get zero returned in place of NULL when there are no matching rows in payments. I'm not seeing any issue issue with `name` vs `id` (could be something I missed. Query designed around OP specification, appeared to be GROUP BY name, even though we are joining on `c.id=p.costid`.

Comment: Im not sure, so is probably better test it on the Fiddle. But because you are joining for `CostID` this is the case Im worried if `[{name: A, Cost:1, Sum: SomeNumber}, {name: A, Cost:3, Sum: Null}`, the the `group by name` will be null.

Comment: `GROUP BY c.name` will work fine.  The `SUM(v.tot_amount)` will be fine. That will include rows with cost rows id in (1,3), you're right that tot_amount for id=3 will be NULL,  but the SUM() aggregate will handle the NULL value. You are right to point out that if we were to use addition operation with a NULL, e.g. `800 + NULL`, the result would be `NULL`.  But the `SUM(v.tot_amount)` will be 80. (If we used `COUNT(v.tot_amount)`, that would return 1. If we used `AVG(v.tot_amount)`, that would return as `80`. The expression `AVG(IFNULL(v.tot_amount,0))` would return `40`.

Comment: What the query *would* omit would be `amount` from rows in `Payment` that are *not* associated with `Cost`.  e.g. a row in `Payment` like this `(pid=5,amount=420,costid=7)` will not match a row in `Cost`, if there is no row in `Cost` with id=7. With the outer join, it depends which table we want to be the driver. The queries above return all rows that are in `Cost`, along with matching rows from `Payment`. Rows in `Payment` that don't match a row in `Cost` will be excluded.

Comment: Yes you are right, `SUM` and `COUNT` just ignore `NULL` dont now why thought return null, sorry.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: It's good to *always* pay attention to NULL values, consider what happens with them. It's when you turn your back and aren't paying attention, that's when the NULL values bite you. `SUM()` will return NULL if *all* of the expressions are NULL, if there aren't any matching rows. That's why we wrap the SUM() in an IFNULL when we want to return a zero in place of the NULL.